# why my session expire after 1440 second after login during activity in php

Tags: php, session, expired-sessions

My session expire in 24 minutes after login.
When I am performing activities continuously, instead it takes latest time and update that, but it saves initially login time and expires according to that. even I have performed activity 1 minute before.

Comment: Set your own session directory and expiration time.

Comment: Please check your app's session config for this setting. Or if you still feel there is something wrong with the app, try including some more information in your question. Perhaps, few lines of your code where you are using session.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your session life time in your php ini file. It would be

```
session.gc_maxlifetime=1440
```

change it with your desired time like :

```
session.gc_maxlifetime=2560
```

See this can help you

https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime

Answer (score 0):

The default timeout for session in PHP is 1440 seconds which is 24 minutes. Hence, your session expires. You can find this setting in `php.ini file` and modify it and restart your server. PHP setting key is

```
session.gc_maxlifetime=1440
```

**Update:**

*As far as my knowledge goes*, a session's expiry doesn't increase if there is any user activity, unless it's done programmatically(voluntarily by the developer). Any session comes with an expiry time and so does the browser behave with the session cookie.

However, if you want the user continue with his activity and not log out, you can either create a session with a long expiry time or refresh session ID using PHP's [`session_regenerate_id()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php).

Comment: agree, session should be updated with latest datetime during any user activity.